# RealmSwift List<String> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

In RealmSwift 3.21.0, I am getting this crash in Realm's Object.swift file where `name: "services"` and `child = { value: 0x0, label: "services" }`:

```
private static func getOptionalPropertyMetadata(
        for child: Mirror.Child,
        at index: Int
    ) -> RLMSwiftPropertyMetadata? {
        guard let name = child.label else {
            return nil
        }
>>>     let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: child.value) //Thread 13: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
        let type = mirror.subjectType
        let code: PropertyType
```

For this model:

```
class RealmAppointment: Object, Codable {
    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return CodingKeys.id.stringValue
    }

    @objc dynamic var id: String
    @objc dynamic var startAt: Date
    @objc dynamic var createdAt: Date! = Date()
    @objc dynamic var updatedAt: Date! = Date()
    let services = List<String>() // var also doesn't work
}
```

The stranger thing is that I have services defined the same way on another Realm Object, and it works:

```
public class RealmOffer: Object, Codable {
    override public static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return CodingKeys.id.stringValue
    }

    static let updatedAtKey = CodingKeys.updatedAt.stringValue

    @objc dynamic public var id: String?
    @objc dynamic public var startAt: Date! = Date()
    @objc dynamic public var createdAt: Date! = Date()
    @objc dynamic public var updatedAt: Date! = Date()
    public var services = List<String>()
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is going to be tough to answer because there's a number of custom classes involved and we don't know their function. Also the code in question is being passed something `private static func getOptionalPropertyMetadata(for child: Mirror.Child,` but we don't know what Mirror.Child represents. Obviously if you later call `child.value` there's some issue there but we would need more visibility into what you're doing and passing. As is we cannot duplicate the issue: Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I stripped some things out to make it more minimal and added some more clarifying details.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, changing the definition of RealmAppointment.services from

```
let services = List<String>()
```

to

```
let services: List<String>! = List<String>()
```

Fixed this crash.